# How to convert unicode to koi8-r?

Tags: python-3.x

I write data to the database, so I want to write lines in a format that has a low weight. One character of the Russian language in utf8 occupies 2 bytes, and in the koi8-r encoding only 1 byte (I am only interested in Russian and English alphabets, the other characters can be ignored).

When in Python I convert the English- Russian string to koi8-r, I get a strange sequence:

```
utf = 'My string, Моя строка'
koi = utf.encode(encoding='koi8-r', errors='ignore')
```

> koi   bytes: b'My string, \xed\xcf\xd1
>   \xd3\xd4\xd2\xcf\xcb\xc1'

When I write these values ​​to the database, I get write- errors.
How I can convert data in 'small format'?

Comment: That output looks like exactly what koi8-r should look like. You're probably doing something wrong in the database interaction. What's the type of the database column you're trying to store this into? You probably need something like varbinary.

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine,  you are converting it into bytes and therefore the errors, you can check the code working fine through simply:

```
utf = 'My string, Моя строка'
koi = utf.encode(encoding='koi8-r', errors='ignore')

print(koi)

print(koi.decode("koi8-r"))
```

The output will be:

```
'My string, Моя строка'
```

Comment: But when I add such data to the database, errors occur.

Comment: @SemenDr because you can't add bytes to the any column the data type etc has to be in sync with the outputs

Comment: I don't need bytes, I need the text is encoded koi8-r